# subscription to redis channel does not keep alive

Tags: c#, python, redis

I have one client subscribe to one channel. After  a certain period of time about 10 minutes idle, the client can not receive any message, but the publish command still returns 1. I've tried  redis-py and servicestack.redis  clients. The only difference is seems the idle period can be little longer when use servicestack.redis.

Any idea?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/redis/issues/detail?id=224

Comment: IMO, you should detail a bit more your network configuration: are the Redis server and clients running on the same box? If not, are they on a LAN? a WAN? Do you have any load balancer or router between them. If yes, is there a idle time out configured? etc ...

Comment: the client and the server are in two LANs. No load balancer or proxy between them. I've just tried to connect them in a same LAN,it works perfectly. Probably there are something configured on the routers. Our administrator is on holiday. I will figure it out after New Year's holiday.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with an older version of Redis that was fixed by the latest version.

As an alternative you could try adding a separate thread that sends a "PING" command once in a while to keep the connection up.